# paperclip destory attachment not deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am facing an embarrassing issue with paperclip. When calling destroy method of the associated model. the database record is deleted , but not the attachment files. 
I have seen the rails server logs, and I see the log "**Deleting attachments**" only, without the logs for deleting the files.

I'm using filename interpolation to rename the uploaded files (see the code).
When I delete this interpolation (removing :path & :url from the model) I notice that destroy method is working correctly. So I am sure of the root cause : filename interpolation.
am I using interpolation in a wrong way? is it a known issue in paperclip?

```
:path =>       ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_photo_file_name.:extension",
:url => 
"/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_photo_file_name.:extension" 


  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_photo_file_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.normalized_photo_file_name
  end

   def normalized_photo_file_name
     if @rnd.nil? 
        @rnd= SecureRandom.hex(4)  
    end
    "photo_#{@rnd}" 

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are. Interpolations are supposed to be reproductible, they should yield exactly the same value for every call for a specific controller and in your case you're generating the random value on all calls.

When the object is destroyed, the interpolation will be called again, it will generate a different random value and it isn't going to find this **new** file. If you really want to have this hex value, generate and store it in your model or instead of using a random use a hashing algorithm like a digest. Here's how it would look like:

```
#put this somewhere
require 'digest/md5'

def normalized_photo_file_name
    "photo_#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.id.to_s)}" 
end
```

This guarantees the same value will be generated for all models and your destroy method is going to behave correctly.

Comment: Ohh! that might be right. but I'm still wondering why the `@rnd` variable is nil when the destroy is called. I'm new in rails, Did I missed something? the aim of `@rnd` was to have always the same random value for next interpolation calls.

Comment: It's an instance variable, it's gone once the instance is gone. You are always loading the object again (and creating a new instance) when you get it from the database.